# retrieve all emails as database in wordpress to view all sent emails

Tags: forms

I have a wordpress CMS website,having contact us page to send email..

can i keep track for the use of this page by sender name,subject, attachment at wordpress admin panel or any other way??

anybody have idea

How to get database

of all received emails from WordPress site's Contact Us Page?

Answer (score 1):

use [Visual Form Builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/). It's a WordPress plugin, allows you to visually build your forms, and keeps track of all entries for you.